# Multiple runs in omnet++ but with new network

Tags: omnet++, veins

I am trying to get different results for the code I have written in veins. I would like to run simulation multiple times to get average of all result. Issue I am facing is when I use `repeat=5` i get exact same result in all 5 runs. I want to regenerate the network each time it repeats. I have written code to place RSUs in random positions but i get same result. What I can try?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Frist of all, see the [TicToc Tutorial](https://omnetpp.org/doc/omnetpp/tictoc-tutorial/).

For your issue, you need to set a seed for each run as the [OMNet Manual show](https://omnetpp.org/doc/omnetpp/manual/#sec:config-sim:repeating-runs-with-different-seeds)

For me, the best way is set `seed-set` as the repetition number(`repeat`)

`seed-set = ${repetition}`

Comment: Hi there, I have tried it. Seed-Set doesn't change anything for me. Always I get same answer.

Comment: i guess i missed something.. working now.. thank you

Answer (score 1):

To start all repetitions of a simulation go to `Run Configurations` and set  `Cmdenv` as `User interface` and:

- for `OMNeT++` 5.0 or older: set `*` (asterisk) in `Runnumber`
- for `OMNeT++` 5.1: set `0..4` in `Run(s)`

As a result you will obtain five set of results.
Optionally you can choose more than one processes to run in parallel or CPUs/processes to use in `Run Configurations`.